# Bytecode manipulation fails on external library

Tags: java, bytecode-manipulation

Hello StackOverflow users,
I'm developing a spigot plugin and I need to use bytecode manipulation to change how a method works, there is no other way before you ask. I'm using javassist, and here's my code:

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        CtClass ctPlayer = pool.get("net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.Entity");
        CtClass ctField = pool.get("int");

        CtField newField = new CtField(ctField, "creativeMode", ctPlayer);
        ctPlayer.addField(newField, "0");

        CtMethod moveMethod = ctPlayer.getDeclaredMethod("move");
        moveMethod.insertBefore("if(creativeMode == 1){\n" +
                "            this.a(this.getBoundingBox().d(d0, d1, d2));\n" +
                "            this.recalcPosition();\n" +
                "            return;\n" +
                "        }");

        CtMethod collideMethod = ctPlayer.getDeclaredMethod("collide");
        collideMethod.insertBefore(" if(creativeMode == 1){\n" +
                "            return;\n" +
                "        }");

        CtMethod inBlockMethod = ctPlayer.getDeclaredMethod("inBlock");
        inBlockMethod.insertBefore(" if(creativeMode == 1){\n" +
                "            return false;\n" +
                "        }");

        ctPlayer.toClass();
```

And here's the exception that is thrown:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: loader (instance of  sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "net/minecraft/server/v1_12_R1/Entity"
```

Is it because Spigot uses a custom class loader to load plugins or is because I'm doing something wrong?w